# How to bring network up on boot?

Tags: boot, networking, 17.10

Ubuntu 17.10 server. Wired network is not starting on boot.

/etc/network interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

If after booting up I do `sudo dhclient eno1` network starts successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

I must add that other answers to similar question include a reference to `/etc/init.d/networking` - I do not have this file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ifupdown package, which managed the network, has been deprecated in favor of netplan in 17.10. The package is no longer present on new installs. The new installer will generate a configuration file for netplan in /etc/netplan, which will set up the system to configure the network via systemd-networkd (in Ubuntu Server) or NetworkManager (in Ubuntu Desktop) https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes

Make sure that the original netplan config file is there. It should up the wired connection automatically and use DHCP to assign an IP address. Assuming the network interface name is 'eno1'.

cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
```

Generate the required configuration

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
```

Reboot

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have `/etc/init.d/networking` it indicates that [ifupdown](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/ifupdown) package is missing. This package is not installed if you skip network configuration during ubuntu setup.

Install it with `apt-get install ifupdown` and reboot. More info: [interfaces(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/interfaces.5.html)